# EJS view engine with express - View file load time

Tags: express, ejs

I am using ejs view engine for express. All my views are present in the views folder.

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

My question is related to rendering part. I use below line to render a view

```
res.render('pages/index');
```

The part which I wanted to confirm is whether

```
(1) express loads all views file in memory at the time of server start and then uses it for rendering view with variable subsitution or
  (2) whether at the time of rendering view it reads the content of the view file and renders it.
```

First one is obviously a huge optimization. I guess express follows the first apporach but just wanted to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

In my mind the second one is used. You can put one million view in your ejs folder and dont see the memory increase.

Comment: Actually I looked into the code of express. It does a lazy loading of views file and caches it. That's why you didn't saw the memory increase but you will see a increase in memory if all views have been used once